# A permutation graph determines a unique permutation

Tags: graph-theory, permutations

Contrary to what we can read in this Wiki page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_graph 
At least for labeled graphs, it seems like the mapping $\sigma \mapsto G_\sigma$ , from the permutations set on $n$ letters to the set of labeled graphs on $n$ vertices, $\textbf{is injective}$. 
Where $G_\sigma$ here is the permutation graph of $\sigma$, that is, a graph with $n$ (labeled) vertices and edges between $i$ and $j$ for every pair $i, j$ for which $i<j$ and $\sigma(i)>\sigma(j)$ , such pairs are called inversions of $\sigma$.

We can show it by induction, but I am looking for a more straight forward argument, can we prove it without using induction?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that we have a very boring round-robin tournament. There are players $1, 2, \dots, n$ and each of them has a skill level $\sigma(1), \sigma(2), \dots, \sigma(n)$. Every pair of players play once, and the player with the higher skill level always wins.

The mapping from $\sigma$ to tournament results is clearly injective. In particular, $\sigma(i)$ is $1$ more than player $i$'s score in the tournament.

The tournament results are in bijection with $G_{\sigma}$. For every pair of players $i,j$, we can determine who won by checking if $G_{\sigma}$ contains edge $ij$, and vice versa. (Having an edge corresponds to $\min\{i,j\}$ winning; no edge corresponds to $\max\{i,j\}$ winning.)

Therefore the mapping $\sigma \mapsto G_{\sigma}$ is also injective.

---

This gives a short algorithm to go from $G_{\sigma}$ back to $\sigma$, which we can summarize as follows:

1. Turn $G_{\sigma}$ into a [tournament](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tournament_(graph_theory)) $T_{\sigma}$; for each pair $i<j$, if $G_{\sigma}$ has edge $ij$, then $T_{\sigma}$ is given edge $(i,j)$, otherwise $T_{\sigma}$ is given edge $(j,i)$.
2. For each $i$, $\sigma(i)$ is given by $1$ plus the outdegree of vertex $i$ in $T_{\sigma}$.